# How to remove datatypes for Integer in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB.
I have inserted some rows in a collection which contains integers and strings.

Previously, they look like normal integer values.

```
Ex : age : 30 , work_status : 1
```

But now, They are looking like

```
Ex : age : NumberLong(30) , work_status : NumberLong(1) .
```

I dont know why they had changed like this.
I need the rows to get revert like old fashion . what should I do?

Please help me in solving the issue.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could basically loop over all the documents and update the values.

Try something like below

```
var cursor = db.<collection-name>.find()

while (cursor.hasNext()) { var doc = cursor.next(); db.<collection-name>.update({_id:doc._id}, {$set: {age: parseInt(doc.age.toString())}}) }
```

You can execute this directly in your mongo console.

PS. If you want to repeat the while block for testing then you might also have to execute the "var cursor = db..." command everytime.